# Merge PDF files using CSV file list using Powershell

Tags: powershell, csv, file, pdf-generation

I want to create multiple merged PDF files from around 1400+ pdf files.

I have a data.csv file with 2 columns as below.
The PDF files with filename matching Filename column and data.csv file are in the same folder.

I need to create multiple merged PDF files and each merged PDF will have group of files that have the same First three characters in the filename.

e.g.,
The filenames starting with EIN* need to be merged into one PDF file in the same sorting order as in the data.csv file. The filename of merged PDF should be Y followed by the first three characters. so in this example it should be YEIN.pdf

This process need to be looped in until all the rows in data.csv are actioned.

> sample data.csv file

FilePath    Filename

$FilePath1  EINCO01-174.pdf

$FilePath2  EINCO02-174.pdf

$FilePath3  EINCO03-174.pdf

$FilePath4  EINCO04-174.pdf

$FilePath5  EINCL01-174.pdf

$FilePath6  EINCL02-174.pdf

$FilePath7  EINCL03-174.pdf

$FilePath8  EINCL04-174.pdf

$FilePath9  EINCL05-174.pdf

$FilePath10 EINCL06-174.pdf

$FilePath11 EINCL07-174.pdf

$FilePath12 EINCL08-174.pdf

$FilePath13 EINCL09-174.pdf

$FilePath14 EINCL10-174.pdf

$FilePath15 EINCL11-174.pdf

$FilePath16 EINCL12-174.pdf

$FilePath17 EINCL13-174.pdf

$FilePath18 EINCL14-174.pdf

$FilePath19 EINCL15-174.pdf

$FilePath20 EINCL16-174.pdf

$FilePath21 EINCL17-174.pdf

$FilePath22 EINCL18-174.pdf

$FilePath23 EINCL19-174.pdf

$FilePath25 GINLG01-170.pdf

$FilePath26 GINLG02-166.pdf

$FilePath27 GINLG03-159.pdf

$FilePath28 GINLG04-159.pdf

$FilePath29 GINLG05-168.pdf

$FilePath30 GINLG06-152.pdf

$FilePath31 GINNO01-174.pdf

$FilePath32 GINNO02-131.pdf

$FilePath33 GINNO04-150.pdf

$FilePath34 GINNO05-174.pdf

$FilePath35 GINTA01-130.pdf

$FilePath36 GINTA02-139.pdf

$FilePath37 GINTA03-139.pdf

So to tackle this I have created a script to split data.csv file into multiple CSV files grouped by the First three characters as below.

```
$data = Import-Csv '.\data.csv' | 
Select-Object Filepath,Filename,@{n='Group';e={$_.Filename.Substring(0,3)}}
$data | Format-Table -GroupBy Group
Group-Object {$_.Group}| ForEach-Object {
$_.Group | Export-Csv "$($_.Group).csv" -NoTypeInformation
}   
foreach ($Group in $data | Group Group)
{     
$data | Where-Object {$_.Group -eq $group.name} | 
    ConvertTo-Csv -delimiter "`t" -NoTypeInformation | 
    foreach {$_.Replace('"','')} | 
    Out-File "$($group.name).csv" 
   }`
```

From here, I have developed another script.ps1 to read a CSV file and create Merged PDF file based on the list of filenames in each CSV file (e.g., EIN.csv) as below. This is working fine.

However, I need to know how to replicate this code for each CSV file in that folder. I don't know how to do it. Any help please.

```
python.exe .\create_from_template.py template_source_list_files .\EIN.csv > part1script.ps1
python.exe .\create_from_template.py template_sort_merge_destination_files .\EIN.csv > part2script.ps1
Get-Content part1script.ps1, part2script.ps1 | Set-Content execute.ps1
.\execute.ps1
```

PS: I have installed PSWritePDF module on my machine.

Comment: Do a search for "create pdf programmatically".  One popular way is to export from work.  So you would need to import multiple pdf into word and then create a new word document.

Comment: Hi K J, I have tried the method you said, but on my work laptop, I cannot run that it seems there are admin right issues and it's going to take forever to get that sorted out.

Answer (score 0):

Having tried out PSWritePDF for your case I would traditionally either use cmd to fresh list all EIN files and in Excel sort. Or, as you already have the lists, simply export the sections to text.ps1 to run separately. NOTE there is a much simpler way but follow the logic here.

So for your first example (change to your paths as required) Once you have a system, it's faster to step and repeat. A few seconds to run the batches so a master list would be multiple groups here just one group of say 60 (1 hour to build and run ?). However see after,

`cmd>powershell C:\Apps\PDF\PSWritePDF\yein.ps1`

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser
$F01 = "C:\Apps\PDF\PSWritePDF\Input\EINCO01-174.pdf"
$F02 = "C:\Apps\PDF\PSWritePDF\Input\EINCO02-174.pdf"
$F03 = "C:\Apps\PDF\PSWritePDF\Input\EINCO03-174.pdf"
$F04 = "C:\Apps\PDF\PSWritePDF\Input\EINCO04-174.pdf"
$F05 = "C:\Apps\PDF\PSWritePDF\Input\EINCL01-174.pdf"
$F06 = "C:\Apps\PDF\PSWritePDF\Input\EINCL02-174.pdf"
$F07 = "C:\Apps\PDF\PSWritePDF\Input\EINCL03-174.pdf"
$F08 = "C:\Apps\PDF\PSWritePDF\Input\EINCL04-174.pdf"
$F09 = "C:\Apps\PDF\PSWritePDF\Input\EINCL05-174.pdf"
$F10 = "C:\Apps\PDF\PSWritePDF\Input\EINCL06-174.pdf"
$F11 = "C:\Apps\PDF\PSWritePDF\Input\EINCL07-174.pdf"
$F12 = "C:\Apps\PDF\PSWritePDF\Input\EINCL08-174.pdf"
$F13 = "C:\Apps\PDF\PSWritePDF\Input\EINCL09-174.pdf"
$F14 = "C:\Apps\PDF\PSWritePDF\Input\EINCL10-174.pdf"
$F15 = "C:\Apps\PDF\PSWritePDF\Input\EINCL11-174.pdf"
$F16 = "C:\Apps\PDF\PSWritePDF\Input\EINCL12-174.pdf"
$F17 = "C:\Apps\PDF\PSWritePDF\Input\EINCL13-174.pdf"
$F18 = "C:\Apps\PDF\PSWritePDF\Input\EINCL14-174.pdf"
$F19 = "C:\Apps\PDF\PSWritePDF\Input\EINCL15-174.pdf"
$F20 = "C:\Apps\PDF\PSWritePDF\Input\EINCL16-174.pdf"
$F21 = "C:\Apps\PDF\PSWritePDF\Input\EINCL17-174.pdf"
$F22 = "C:\Apps\PDF\PSWritePDF\Input\EINCL18-174.pdf"
$F23 = "C:\Apps\PDF\PSWritePDF\Input\EINCL19-174.pdf"
$OUT = "C:\Apps\PDF\PSWritePDF\Output\YEIN.pdf"
Merge-PDF -InputFile $F01, $F02, $F03, $F04, $F05, $F06, $F07, $F08, $F09, $F10, $F11, $F12, $F13, $F14, $F15, $F16, $F17, $F18, $F19, $F20, $F21, $F22, $F23 -OutputFile $OUT
```

What you would need to do is consider each group as separate, but from the structured way your grouping we can say there are just 2 pre-process steps.

Merge EINCO##
Merge EINCL##

Which are not alphabetic but could be listed in order to simply merge alpha-numerically the 2 sets then merge those 2sets.

Thus if we **template** a single merge from 00 to 99 we can speed up the merge for each set so here is an outline. (It does not matter if there is NO 00 or up to 99 it will simply run any that are available between the two).

So at this point we can write a header for the first 2 sets similar to this:

Merge00-99.ps1 (here we ASSume all files end in `-174.pdf`)

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser
$Fin = "C:\Apps\PDF\PSWritePDF\Input\EINCO"
$Ext = "-174.pdf"
$Out = "C:\Apps\PDF\PSWritePDF\Input\EINCO-Out.pdf"
$F00 = "$Fin"+"00"+"$Ext"
$F01 = "$Fin"+"01"+"$Ext"
$F02 = "$Fin"+"02"+"$Ext"
...
$F98 = "$Fin"+"98"+"$Ext"
$F99 = "$Fin"+"99"+"$Ext"
Merge-PDF -OutputFile $Out -InputFile $F00, $F01, $F02, $F03, $F04, $F05, $F06, $F07, $F08, $F09, $F10, $F11, $F12, $F13, $F14, $F15, $F16, $F17, $F18, $F19, $F20, $F21, $F22, $F23, $F24, $F25, $F26, $F27, $F28, $F29, $F30, $F31, $F32, $F33, $F34, $F35, $F36, $F37, $F38, $F39, $F40, $F41, $F42, $F43, $F44, $F45, $F46, $F47, $F48, $F49, $F50, $F51, $F52, $F53, $F54, $F55, $F56, $F57, $F58, $F59, $F60, $F61, $F62, $F63, $F64, $F65, $F66, $F67, $F68, $F69, $F70, $F71, $F72, $F73, $F74, $F75, $F76, $F77, $F78, $F79, $F80, $F81, $F82, $F83, $F84, $F85, $F86, $F87, $F88, $F89, $F90, $F91, $F92, $F93, $F94, $F95, $F96, $F97, $F98, $F99
```

OK that works for EINCO = 4 merged files, & EINCL is only 19 merged Files. And we can add those two together in a 2nd'ry list to generate YEIN as 23  merged files. That can be simplified to a Universal ## Module to be used from a script

**PDFmerge##.ps1**

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser
$Fin = $args[0]
$Ext = $args[1]
$Out = $args[2]
echo "Merging $Fin##$Ext to $Out"
for ($i=0; $i -lt 10; $i++) {
    for ($j=0; $j -lt 10; $j++) {
        New-Variable -Name "F$i$j" -Value "$Fin$i$j$Ext"
    }
}
echo Processing
Merge-PDF -OutputFile $Out -InputFile $F00, $F01, $F02, $F03, $F04, $F05, $F06, $F07, $F08, $F09, $F10, $F11, $F12, $F13, $F14, $F15, $F16, $F17, $F18, $F19, $F20, $F21, $F22, $F23, $F24, $F25, $F26, $F27, $F28, $F29, $F30, $F31, $F32, $F33, $F34, $F35, $F36, $F37, $F38, $F39, $F40, $F41, $F42, $F43, $F44, $F45, $F46, $F47, $F48, $F49, $F50, $F51, $F52, $F53, $F54, $F55, $F56, $F57, $F58, $F59, $F60, $F61, $F62, $F63, $F64, $F65, $F66, $F67, $F68, $F69, $F70, $F71, $F72, $F73, $F74, $F75, $F76, $F77, $F78, $F79, $F80, $F81, $F82, $F83, $F84, $F85, $F86, $F87, $F88, $F89, $F90, $F91, $F92, $F93, $F94, $F95, $F96, $F97, $F98, $F99
echo "Done Merging $F00 - $F99"
```

Externally we can simply run for the two batches into one

YEIN.bat

```
powershell -file PDFmerge##.ps1 "input/EINCO" "-174.pdf" "output/Part01.pdf"
powershell -file PDFmerge##.ps1 "input/EINCL" "-174.pdf" "output/Part02.pdf"
powershell -file PDFmerge##.ps1 "output/Part" ".pdf" "output/YEIN.pdf"
```

Now we come to the wrinkles GINLG all have different -### tails

```
$FilePath25 GINLG01-170.pdf
$FilePath26 GINLG02-166.pdf
...
$FilePath30 GINLG06-152.pdf
```

As the merged files don't include those numbers as Bookmarks or any other feature we could simply rename those tails and not miss them, thus for a workset it makes sense to have a copy simply by cmd
`ren ???????*.PDF ???????.pdf` so directory list is much simplified

```
EINCL01.pdf   EINCL02.pdf   EINCL03.pdf   EINCL04.pdf   EINCL05.pdf   EINCL06.pdf  
EINCL07.pdf   EINCL08.pdf   EINCL09.pdf   EINCL10.pdf   EINCL11.pdf   EINCL12.pdf  
EINCL13.pdf   EINCL14.pdf   EINCL15.pdf   EINCL16.pdf   EINCL17.pdf   EINCL18.pdf  
EINCL19.pdf   EINCO01.pdf   EINCO02.pdf   EINCO03.pdf   EINCO04.pdf   .....
```

Now we can speedily group all sets and only need to merge the 5 letter outs into pairs or triplets or whatever by a much smaller master set of merges.

### However

At this point I would be using Excel to output a cmd file that has columns as text

```
ren EINCO01-174.pdf EIN01.pdf
...
ren EINCL01-174.pdf EIN05.pdf
...
ren EINCL19-174.pdf EIN23.pdf
... etc.
```

Then just merge EIN in desired 00-99 order to output YEIN.pdf thus generating minimum merges for exactly 1400 files.

Note when export the list as cmd you may need to tidy up but it is a very quick Find and Replace, however, note I ADDED a space after REN in its column, and one before the second _EIN to ensure whilst removing auto tabbing the spaces were retained.

RenEIN.cmd

[image]

### **Now we can do all 1400 in one line**

**Remove the echo after testing for the full run**:

```
for %f in (EIN GIN etc ...) do echo powershell -file PDFmerge##.ps1 "input/%f" ".pdf" "output/Y%f.pdf"
```