# Merging PDFs using powershell and VBA

Tags: vba, powershell, ms-access, pdf

Hello I just trying to using VBA in Microsoft Access and powershell (command Merge-Pdf) merge different PDF files based on checkbox. I want if they are checked, take them and merge them into one PDF document by clicking on one button. I just have usign another button to open all checked documents, but I also wan to merge these chosen documents.

I try something, but it do not work.

My tested VBS looks like:

```
Function MergeSelectedPDF()

    ' Declare variables
    Dim PowerShellCmd As String
    Dim selectedPDFs As String
    Dim shellCommand As String
    Dim shellResult As Variant

    ' Initialize selectedPDFs variable
    selectedPDFs = ""

    ' Loop through your records and build a string with selected PDF file paths
    Dim rs As Recordset
    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Tabulka1")
    
    Do While Not rs.EOF
        If rs![Marker] = True Then
            ' Separate file paths with spaces
            selectedPDFs = selectedPDFs & " " & rs![Odkaz]
        End If
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop
    
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing

    ' Construct the PowerShell command
    PowerShellCmd = selectedPDFs & " | Merge-Pdf -OutputPath ""C:\Merged.pdf"""

    ' Execute the PowerShell command
    shellCommand = "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Command " & PowerShellCmd

    shellResult = Shell(shellCommand, vbNormalFocus)

    ' Check if an error occurred during execution
    If shellResult = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Error executing PowerShell command.", vbExclamation
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: What does "do not work" mean - error message, wrong result, nothing happens? Do you have Adobe Pro installed?

Comment: In the previous code I try to call powershell command Merge-Pdf which should merge given PDF files, but in this case there is no output. It looks like that it run but nothing happens. I dont have Adobe Pro, I want to do it with available tools.

Comment: I have old VBA that merges PDF files but requires Adobe Pro to be installed. Are you saying that Powershell can do this without Adobe Pro installed?

Comment: Yes, there is a module (https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/MergePdf/1.1) what should be able to merge PDF files. I try to use it but probably there is problem with my syntax or something like that...

Comment: I suggest you troubleshoot the Powershell code directly in powershell console and you'll lilely get an error message that helps you work out whats going on. I expect that the error message is being hidden. So many people make this mistake of building complicated code and scratching their head when it "doesn't work". Take an example of one Powershell command line and run it interactively. Don't try and build something complicated and try to get it working in one go

Comment: Installing module too complicated for me. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are attempting to write to the root folder (plus many other shell problems e.g. command lines have length limits so end of command line will be cut off and thus your firing a loaded cannon at root of hard drive.)

```
' Construct the PowerShell command
    PowerShellCmd = selectedPDFs & " | Merge-Pdf -OutputPath ""C:\Merged.pdf"""
```

That is not allowed (unless you unwisely unprotected it).

[image]

Use a test folder such as C:\test then write to that sub folder, ensuring you set user writes as permission if necessary.

Also ensure your privileges are set correctly for that PowerShell module when installed . There are much easier ways to merge files without PowerShell restrictions by using a single command line in the shell with a single exe such as PDFcpu https://pdfcpu.io/core/merge and many others like GhostScript, cpdf, qpdf, poppler pdfunite etc. (fastest is likely to be https://mupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mutool-merge.html )

Keep the number of files very low, as with paths the string length character limits will kick in very soon. HENCE simply write a text list of filenames and pass the list OR shortnames to the merge command.

This example uses numeric approach within powershell not externalised as such but whilst it works for hundreds it is not most efficient  https://stackoverflow.com/a/75524955/10802527 .  Efficient is using the shell with a batch file.

So here using GhostScript with a text file of commands or files https://stackoverflow.com/a/75486958/10802527